# Endomorphism such as $f^{2}-f=2Id$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to understand this problem about endomorphism :

Let $E$ be a vector space on $\mathbb{R}$ such as $dimE \geq 1$
Let $f$ be an endomorphism of $E$ such as $f^2-f=2Id_E$, $f\ne-Id_E$ and $f\neq 2Id_E$

1)Is f inversible ?

I would say we have $f(\frac{1}{2}(f-Id))=Id_E$ then f is inversible with $f^{-1}=\frac{1}{2}(f-Id)$

2)Is f diagonalizable ?

We have $f^2-f-2Ide=0$ then if $f\ne-Id_E$ and $f\neq 2Id_E$ I would say f has not any eigenvalue thus the endomorphism cannot be diagonalizable.

3) What are the eigenvalues of f ?

Refering to the previous question f has not any eigen values.

4) Express the spectral projectors of f according to f

I do not see how to do it if f has not any eigenvalues

Thus I think I made mistakes and the endormophism should have eigenvalues, could you tell me how to understand this problem ?

Thank you

Comment: What are the roots of $X^2-X-2=0$?

Comment: Thanks for you answer thus the eigen values are $-1$ and $2$ thus f is diagonalizable if dim E=2 otherwise it is not ? How could we express the spectral projectors according to f ?

Answer (score 0):

We really must have a closer look at the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $f$.
We are given that $f^2-f=2\operatorname{Id}$, i.e., plugging $f$ into the polynomial $P(X)=X^2-X-2$ gives the zero map. 
Note that $P(X)=(X-2)(X+1)$, which shows that the only *possible* eigenvalues are $2$ and $-1$.
As we are given that $f\ne 2\operatorname{Id}$, there exists $v$ with $f(v)\ne 2v$, so $w:=f(v)-2v\ne 0$. Then 
$$(f+\operatorname{Id})(w)= (f+\operatorname{Id})(f-2\operatorname{Id})(v)=(f^2-v-2\operatorname{Id})(v)=0,$$
which says that $w$ is an eigenvector of eigenvalue $-1$.

Similarly, from $f\ne-\operatorname{Id}$ we find that for $v'$ with $f(v')\ne -v'$ the vector $w':=f(v')+v'\ne0$ is eigenvector of eigenvalue $2$.

Note that this only shows that the eigenspaces for  the eigenvalues $-1$, $2$
are *at least* one-dimensional; they may be much higher-dimensional.

Does this make $f$ diagonalizable? Not per se as there *might* be some non-trivial nilpotent summand in the Jordan decomposition. However, for each $v\in E$ we have $$\tag1v=-\frac13(f(v)-2v)+\frac13(f(v)+v)$$
which shows that $E=\ker(f+\operatorname{Id})\oplus \ker(f-2\operatorname{Id})$, in other words, $f$ is diagonalizable. (Also, $(1)$ contains the spectral projectors)